# Do all sites offer something like recovery codes?

Tags: multi-factor, dropbox

I've always given two-factor authentication a wide berth because of my experience with it; with Dropbox, for example, they want an e-mail confirmation when I log in, but eight minutes pass until I receive the e-mail—if at all—and then the login attempt is already timed-out. The only still working login is from my dropbox.exe ruinning. That was my first experience. Google wanted to know in which month of which year I created my account. (How should I remember? That was a decade ago!!)

So, my first experience with second factor authentication was more of a “dubious factor authentication” experience. Since then, I've avoided any two-factor authentication I could. So that; today, I had to install a 2FA for GitHub because they force me to do. And, they did a really good job with: **you get “recovery codes”** in case your cell phone is broken or stolen.

**My question** now **is, is this common now?** Or, be it special feature of GitHub? Can I use for my Dropbox? But, why didn't Dropbox inform me, I need to download my codes? Still, I'm locked out when my computer breaks (due to the email delay problem). I would like to enable more 2FA, but I do not want to increase the chance of locking myself out. (Really, if an account is important, not being allowed to lock in again, due to your own action, would be very annoying.)

Comment: ... have you checked your Dropbox account? ... it's in the settings.

Comment: This is really something you can look for and try out yourself. "Giving a wide berth" shouldn't mean you won't even check in your own accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be aware that all those *recovery things* are nothing more than backdoors actually lowering the overall security of an authentication system. Simply as the alternative would be manual (meaning here human) identification of a client losing its credentials any company with a great number of client accounts needs an automatic way. It must be noted that this kind of thing only seldom occurs in the corporate world: if you have local admins, it is much more secure to have them to reset a password (and to scold the uncautious user...) than any other *auto* thing. The only acceptable way is when a higher security account is used to recover a lower one.

That being said the more common recovery tools are:

- secret questions. This is the oldest way and the most frowned upon: either the user cannot remember how it exactly wrote the original answer, or anyone with some knowledge about a person can guess the answer... Anyway it is still largely used.
- alternative channels. You generally give an email address that will receive a one time token which can be used to reset the password. Optionaly, a second address (often a phone number) is required to recieve an additional *secret*. That means that an attacker have to know the user name and steal an access to a mailbox (and optionaly a phone number). The good news is that the platform is not responsible for the security of those channels (only the user is) and only store locally non secret informations. The downside is that users can *abandon* phone numbers and/or mail addresses...
- recovery codes/tokens. This is more or less an alternative (loooong) key. A very efficient method. Generally the platform does not store the codes, but only hashes of them, to limit the risk of credential theft. The downside is that as those code are extremely large, they have to be written (generally in plain text) into a file. So an attacker gaining access to that file will immediately be able to impersonate the user

Except for the first one which is deemed poor, the other ways each have their good and bad points. Which one is used is close to a matter of taste of the security officer of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty common. MFA implementations need a way for you to re-gain access to your account if you lose your second factor, and recovery codes are one of the cheapest and easiest way to do that.